# How to map Spring Interceptor

Tags: java, spring, mapping, interceptor, request-mapping

I'm trying to map a Spring Interceptor so it catches every '*.do' request, but I can only make it work in a 'single level'.

My Interceptor mapping path is "/*.do", and I can only intercept URIs like /app/action.do

If I request /app/**anotherLevel**/action.do the Interceptor is not triggered.

I've noticed that mapping path = "/*/*.do" catches 'second level' requests, but that does not look correct.

What should be the value of interceptor mapping path so I can intercept all *.do request regardless of the level?

Thanks a lot and sorry for any english mistakes.

Comment: Have you tried double-asterisk? `**/*.do` would generally be the pattern to use I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to map every level.

There was a slash missing, so the correct value should be `/**/*.do`.

I found the trick in the link below:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver-interceptor

Thanks a lot!